# Calling an Angular 8 WebAPI method to a contoller through a HTTPS GET link

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application, angular8

I'm running an Angular 8 SPA application hosted on ASP.NET Core 3.1 hosted in IIS 10.

I have a use case where the user of the application receives an email that contains an hyperlink to a Web API controller method.

For instance:

> https://test.myapp.fr/api/ExternalCommands/ManageDati?a=C3hl5%2FMgXdldyX4ssmgyayMP3xE%2Bi%2

When this URL is used through an HTTP client (ARC in my case), it works.

If it is used through the default browser, **also hosting the SPA Application**, it fails without reaching the server as is. It is rewritten to reach the **notFound** component:

> https://test.myapp.fr/notFound?a=C3hl5%2FMgXdldyX4ssmgyayMP3xE%2Bi%2

Here is the controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ManageDati(string a, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
}
```

The component:

[image]

What are my options here? Should I host a Web api outside the scope of the SPA App?

EDIT: Here is the default routing configuration:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute("externalcommands", "api/ExternalCommands/{action}/{id?}", defaults: new { controller = "ExternalCommands", action = "ManageDati" });
  routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

EDIT 2:

To prove my point that the request never reaches the server, I've enabled Angular router tracing in `app.router.ts`:

```
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { enableTracing: true })],
...
```

I can see that the Angular router logic is processing my request and redirects to the notFound component.

The same app run in the debugger under IIS Express works: The URL is sent to the server as is, the angular router does nothing.

Very strange indeed.

EDIT 3:

This works with IIS Express / Angular Live development server because they're using differents ports.

Comment: what is the routing of the ManageDati method? in the past I had to tell IIS to ignore the "api" request with a rewrite rule

Comment: I don't understand why do you have the {id?} at the end of the routing. This makes an optional parameter to be used like https://test.myapp.fr/api/ExternalCommands/ManageDati/5 being the 5 the id. Do you need that?

Comment: I use to deploy the Angular app in a subfolder like /app and then your requests to /api will reach IIS

Comment: @JavierFromMadrid Yes, I need the parameter. I'll deploy the api to a different domain to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add URL rewrite rules/settings for your API in web.config file.

by default your domain will look for angular routing (since most of the angular apps will mention SpaRewriteRule as **"*"** or else your IIS hosted application will route to Controller/Action method routes), if you want to restrict angular routing for specific urls you need to add rewrite URL config in web.config file

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SpaRewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="ApiProxyRule" stopProcessing="true"> // add this rule
          <match url="api/(.*)"/> 
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://YOUR_API_URLS/api/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: As soon as the angular app is installed in the browser, it is too late. Angular routing will process all URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Api is always be hidden. If you want to call api, you only do this from angular.

Email contains a url path to angular route instead of api and you should create a component to route what handle this url with params and call api.