# Can I tell the router to let go the requested URL in the browser?

Tags: angular, angular8

This question is a follow-up to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165752/calling-an-angular-8-webapi-method-to-a-contoller-through-a-https-get-link).

I wondered if we could tell the router component to let the navigator handle the URL instead of routing to a component.

In other words, I think I sometimes need to bypass the Angular router.

Comment: Can't you use plain JS for it? For example, `location.href = 'http://desired.url'`.

Comment: @Ivan I do not think so, because I'm clicking a link in a email.